# Error: Unknown columns in caret glm fit

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

Anyone know why I am getting this error? The attribute 'Kön' is actually called 'Kön' in the training file. And I don't have a column with the name training in the training file.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, savePredictions = 
TRUE)


mod_fit <- train(as.factor(training$Riskdrickare)~., data=training, method="glm",family="binomial", trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 5)


Error: Unknown columns 'training', '<U+FEFF>Kön'
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I am suppose to run this code afterwards:

```
pred = predict(mod_fit, newdata=test)

confusionMatrix(data=pred, as.factor(test$Riskdrickare))
```

The warnings states:

```
Warning messages:
1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
3: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
4: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
5: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
6: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
7: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
8: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
9: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
10: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
11: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
12: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

The colum names are:

Kön Ålder   Nationalitet    Fakultet    Riskdrickare    Terminer    Omtenta Sektionsaktiv   studieTim   Träning Frysmat Frukost Vegan   Sömn    Relation    dator   dAlc    wAlc    FamRel  fHealth mhealth Smoke   fSize   fTog    pStudEvent  schemUnd    drickStudenEven fritidVän   FritidTid

They consist of both numerical and categorical values.

A reproducible example would be an equivalent dataset for this assignment.

If I apply `as.factor(Riskdrickare)` then the first error goes away but the rest remain.

Solved:
By setting the encoding to Ansi and remove all the letters 'å'. 'ä' and 'ö' from the colummn names removed the error message.

Comment: caret I presume? If so you should add it as a tag, maybe along with glm.

Comment: Can you write how it should look like? I got the library(caret) above in the script.

Comment: I did it for you then.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with add a tag and maybe along with glm.

Comment: I meant the tags (meta-data), that are light blue under the question. Makes it easier for interested people to find your question as they look for those tags. In this case it is probably an issue with the way the `caret` package handles the `glm` method (these have the tags `r-caret` and `glm`).

Comment: Oh I see, cheers then! You don't have any ideas to why I am having this error? Really annoying error since no have had it before me it seems. Do you think there could be some problems with the names? '<U+FEFF>Kön'

Comment: Not really, would have to look and debug it and I don't have the time at the moment. But I think it is a good question, someone (maybe Max himself?) will eventually have a look I imagine.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).